# Turn internal hardrive into NAS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, nas

I have 2 HDD in my computer, one SSD for my os and main applications, and one mechanical drive, with all my data. I was wondering if there was a way to make this drive available online.
For exemple I can access my drive over my LAN using the simple "Share" functionality of Windows. Would there be a way to make it available online ? Maybe by installing a NAS OS or a bit of software to make this disk available with a UI online ?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean online ? Like access from internet ?

Comment: Yes, I do it all the time. Windows sharing can make the drive accessible on your Intranet, while you can give external access with a web server, FTP server or DLNA/UPnP server.

Comment: @YanivK yes over the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be a way to make it available online?

Technically there is no difference between sharing between your local network and the rest of the network on the Internet. No change is needed at all on your laptop.

However if you are a home user and you are not using the normal Internet access via one or more IPs per computer but instead are using NAT then it becomes problematic. In that case your computer probably does not have a regular IP but one of the RFC1918 IPs which are explicitly not routed to the Internet. That leaves you these choices:

1. Do not try to access the limited IP address assigned to your laptop from the Internet. Instead configure your firewall for port forwarding.  (Not the firewall on your laptop, the firewall in your "modem/router/accesspoint/DNSserver/DHCPserver/switch"-multi-thingy.
2. Use a normal IP address for the laptop. (Which is how the Internet was designed to work and what was used until we ran out out IP v4 addresses).
3. Use an IP v6 address. IP v6 is two decades old. It should be present in just about any location.  (Note, *should* is not *is*. 20-ish years is a long time but some ISPs are seriously backward).
4. Or add the drive to some computer which is reachable from the Internet. You will be able to access it from anywhere, but not at the same speed as something on your local network.